# Stringing an array in function c++/cli

Tags: c++-cli

```
private: void rikiavimas(array<String^>^ A[],int j)
```

This does not seem to work. I'm not very familiar with c++/cli , so can you help me out? I want A[] to become a stringed array

Answer (score 0):

`array<String^>^` is already an array of strings. You don't need the `[]` as well.

(I'm assuming that's what you meant by "stringed" array. Please correct me if not.)

Comment: That is what I meant. Thanks :)